# Plot AspectRatio basic question

Tags: plotting, options

When Plotting (using the command `Plot`), `AspectRatio->Automatic` means :

[image]

The explanation of `Automatic` from mathematica help file, was not easy understand for me.

I want to explain it in other way :

> If
> the actual length from (0,0) to (1,0) in the plot is *k* pixels, then
> the actual length from (0,0) to (0,1) in the plot is *k* pixels also.

Now the question : How can I set AspectRatio, so that

> If
> the actual length from (0,0) to (1,0) in the plot is *k* pixels, then
> the actual length from (0,0) to (0,1) in the plot is *2k* pixels ?

**I just got a message from a user, and I voted `yes` for the message since it was useful. Then my question was closed(I didn't expect that). The message was useful but I still do not know exactly how to achieve this.

Can anyone help me with a comment ?**

Note that `AspectRatio->1/2` is not a correct answer.

[image]

As you see in the above screenshot,
the length of (0,0) to (0, 0.1) is much much longer than
the length of (0,0) to (0.1, 0).
Not just twice longer.

+-+-+-+-+-+-+ After some comments and answers -+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-

In my PC, @Michael E2's second solution (=following code) works fine. Below is a screenshot on my PC.

```
Plot[6 Exp[-t/10] Sin[t], {t, 0, 20}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
 ScalingFunctions -> {2 # &, #/2 &}]
```

[image]

@Michael E2's wrote that his second solution is not good because there is unwanted, strange logarithmic peak. But in my PC, there is no such  `logarithmic peak phenomenon`. I am using mathematica V12.2.

Comment: Regarding your "on close" additional question. Such questions can be discussed on [Meta](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/), but this one is [answered in Help](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/duplicates).

Comment: Thank you, can you teach me again?

Comment: What do you want to learn?

Comment: How can I set AspectRatio -> ??? so that `the actual length from (0,0) to (0,1) in the plot` is double of `the actual length from (0,0) to (1,0) in the plot`

Comment: The wording of your question is not clear. The thread I linked to contains all the information you need to understand how `AspectRatio` works.

Comment: Thank you, main point may be use `ImageSize -> Automatic -> {a, b}`.

Comment: Simply set  `AspectRatio -> 1/2`

Comment: @Daniel Huber, that's not correct. In fact, that is why I asked this question! I will update it in the post.

Comment: You need to make the plot, get the `PlotRange`, and then compute the `AspectRatio` to give the desired scaling. You can then impose the new aspect ratio with `Show[]`. You might be able to do it with `ScalingFunctions` like this: `Plot[x, {x, 0, 10}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, ScalingFunctions -> {2 # &, #/2 &}]` (but why does it produce logarithmically spaced ticks?)

Comment: @Michael E2, Thank you. I think that is the ultimate answer!

Comment: And I feel my question is easy but the answer is quite hard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the plot,
get the plot range,
and then compute the aspect ratio to give the desired scaling.
You can then impose the new aspect ratio with `Show[]`:

```
plot = Plot[6 Exp[-t/10] Sin[t], {t, 0, 20},
   Prolog ->(* to show aspect ratio is correct *)
    {Magenta, Opacity[0.5], Rectangle[{0, 0}, {10, 5}]}
   ];
aspRatio = 2 Ratios[Differences /@ PlotRange@plot][[1, 1]];
Show[plot, AspectRatio -> aspRatio]
```

[image]

You might produce the desired plot with `ScalingFunctions` like the following (but why does it produce logarithmically spaced ticks?):

```
Plot[6 Exp[-t/10] Sin[t], {t, 0, 20},
 AspectRatio -> Automatic, ScalingFunctions -> {2 # &, #/2 &}
 ]
```

[image]

Note that the scaling functions messes up the coordinate system, so that if you include the `Prolog` from the first plot, it would need its coordinates scaled to match the plot (i.e., `Rectangle[{0, 0}, {10, 10}]`). I didn't feel it was worth showing this.

Comment: Thank you, but which mathematica version are you using ? I'm 12.2 and the code `Plot[6 Exp[-t/10] Sin[t], {t, 0, 20}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
 ScalingFunctions -> {2 # &, #/2 &}]` works perfectly fine. There is no logarithmic peak on my PC.

Comment: Michael was talking about the spacing of the ticks on the $y$-axis in the last picture, @imida. Can you take a screenshot of what you have?

Comment: Yes I uploaded a screenshot of my PC. Am I understanding correctly?

Comment: @imidak Yep, yours look right. I'm on V13.1/Mac. I'm pretty sure I saw this problem in V13.0.  Maybe earlier, maybe not...bad memory recall.

Comment: Then.. it is more strange then expected. Mathematica V 12.2, windows 10.

Comment: @imidak Graph and the ticks are scaled and placed correctly, but the ticks shown are not regular. They (that is, 0.5, 1.0, 2.0, 5.0) are chosen as though the graph was supposed to be a log plot.

Comment: Thank you again, so even in V13.1/Mac, mathematica is not wrong, but a little strange phenomemon is observed(irregular ticks)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a function which sets up the *unit aspect ratio* for a plot:

```
setUnitAspectRatio[unitAspectRatio_ : 1/2][plot_Graphics] := Module[{xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax},
  {{xmin, xmax}, {ymin, ymax}} = 
   "PlotRange" /. ResourceFunction["GraphicsInformation"][plot];
  Show[plot, AspectRatio -> unitAspectRatio (ymax - ymin)/(xmax - xmin)]]
```

It can be used as follows.

Suppose we have a plot (the prolog shows a rectange with width `1/2` and height `1` in the units of the internal coordinate system of `Graphics`):

```
plot = Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, Prolog -> {Green, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1/2., 1}]}]
```

> [image: output]

To set it up in such a way that this rectangle will become a square on the canvas (i.e., in pixels), we proceed as follows:

```
newplot = setUnitAspectRatio[1/2]@plot
```

> [image: output]

Checking the pixel size of the rectangle:

```
ImageDimensions@ImageCrop[Show[newplot, Axes -> False] /. _Line :> (## &[])]
```

> ```
> {230, 231}
> ```

It is a square accurately to one pixel, as expected.